# getServletContext().getResource("/").getPath() doesn't work in OPENSHIFT

Tags: java, tomcat7, openshift

I'm trying to read a file in a jsp file and I'm receiving invalid url or null. I have uploaded my java project to `Openshift` on tomcat 7 server. I get the error not found File.

The following code returns `/localhost/IPPC/file.txt` but i get error that the file doesn't exist. IPPC is the name of my `.war` file. I try to get the path with the command:

```
getServletContext().getResource("/").getPath()
```

I'm uploading a `.war` file in `Openshift`. How can i get the path in order to read a file?

Comment: Try `getServletContext().getResource(File.separator).getPath()`.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it and i'll give feedback to you

Comment: It doesn't work for me! Can anyone else help me?